# Alternative to Classic ASP flow control

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I'm trying to wean myself off of Classic ASP.  I've developed alternative techniques to handle just about everything in HTML/JavaScript.  However, I still need some way to replace the following:

```
<% if this then %>
    <div>Wow.  This.  Totally this.  Isn't this great?</div>
<% else %>
    <div>You're really missing out on this.</div>
<% end if %>
```

Is there a way to accomplish conditional branching / conditional code in pure HTML/ JavaScript?

Comment: You are looking for HTML templating, look into libraries like Handlebars or Mustache. (It's a bit confusing though that you want to replace a server side language with a client side language, that's not entirely the same thing.)

Comment: Like @Tomalak say's HTML is client-side *(render at the client)* while ASP code is server-side *(meaning it is processed before being sent back to the client)* they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Lankymart Not necessarily mutually exclusive, but it's certainly a topic to make one's mind about.

Comment: @Tomalak I meant you can't have one without the other, the server has to generate the content in the first place for the content to be rendered in the client.

Comment: I understand the difference between server and client side events and content.  I'm asking if there is any way to replace this server side scripting with something equivalent on the client side.

Comment: @Tomalak, thanks for the recommend.  I've played with templating a bit.  But does it have any mechanism for conditional branching like in my example?

Comment: It's in the documentation. http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html

Comment: The usual way to accomplish something like this client-side is to include both versions in the html, with different IDs or classes, and then use client-side scripting to manipulate the CSS to conditionally hide the one that shouldn't show (or show the one that shouldn't be hidden; you need to decide whether the text needs to be hidden by default or shown by default). The downside is that all of the text will be right there in the source for all the world to see.

Comment: Output the response from a function instead of doing it inline. Handle the logic inside the function.

Comment: @Tomalak.... Now THAT looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

client side scripting's document.writeln:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <br />Some html code before<br /><br />
    <script language="javascript">
        var This = true;
        if(This){
            document.writeln("<div>Wow.  This.  Totally this.  Isn't this great?</div>");
        }
        else{
            document.writeln("<div>You're really missing out on this.</div>");
        }
    </script>
    <br />Some html code after<br /><br />
    <script language="javascript">
        var This = false;
        if(This){
            document.writeln("<div>Wow.  This.  Totally this.  Isn't this great?</div>");
        }
        else{
            document.writeln("<div>You're really missing out on this.</div>");
        }
    </script>
    <br />Some other html code after<br /><br />
</body>
```

Note: In you example you used "this", I used "This", "this" in javascript is a reserved word

Comment: AKA - how to SEO-proof your content.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to take on board @Martha's comment and use Javascript together with CSS to give a div's CSS display property the value `inline` or `none` as appropriate.  This would keep the HTML and the JS separate.

Comment: @Diodeus the question didn't clarify if the need was for internet web site or intranet web application. In the first case you're right ;-)

Comment: @John.  Yes, I like Martha's approach better, too.  ANd I would vote it the answer if she had posted it as such.  In fact, in the year and a half since I originally asked this, her (?) approach is exactly the way I have gone, with much success.